# How do I fix this: Client auth is required but no trust anchors found in: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates/default/trusted

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt, neo4j

I've been trying to configure SSL for a Neo4j server [per their documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/ssl-framework/). To this end I have created the following directory structure.

```
/var/lib/neo4j/certificates# ls -lR
.:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 4 neo4j neo4j 4096 Dec 20 17:12 default
-rw------- 1 neo4j neo4j  985 Dec 20 13:29 neo4j.cert
-rw------- 1 neo4j neo4j 1704 Dec 20 13:29 neo4j.key

./default:
total 16
-r--r--r-- 1 neo4j neo4j 1704 Dec 20 17:08 private.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 neo4j neo4j 3461 Dec 20 17:18 public.crt
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo4j neo4j 4096 Dec 20 17:12 revoked
drwxr-xr-x 2 neo4j neo4j 4096 Dec 20 17:12 trusted
```

public.crt is the fullchain.pem file and private.key is the privkey.pem from the letsencrypt directory. `trusted` and `revoked` are empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the public certificate is also in the `trusted` directory, as explained in the [Neo4J documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/ssl-framework/#ssl-certificates):

> The public certificate must be duplicated. One copy is to be placed into the `base_directory`, and the other copy is to be placed into the `trusted_dir`

Got the same problem and copying the public certificate to the `trusted` folder solved it.

Comment: Thanks, @keldon . I was able to make it work by copying the cert file to the trusted directory. Copying the private key along with the cert file caused issues too; had to be the cert file alone!